# Let $f: [0, 2\pi] \to \Bbb R$. If the codomain is equipped with the topology produced by the sets $(a, \infty)$, then determine the topology induced.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f: [0, 2\pi] \to \Bbb R, f(x) = \sin x$. If the codomain is equipped with the topology produced by the sets $(a, \infty)$, then determine the topology induced.

To determine the induced topology It seems the best way is to look at the preimages that $(a, \infty)$ produces?

If $a\ge 1$, then $f^{-1}[(1,\infty)] = \{x \in \Bbb R : \sin x \in (1, \infty) \} = \emptyset$

If $a<-1$, then $f^{-1}[(-1, \infty)] = \{x \in \Bbb R : \sin x \in (-1, \infty) \} = (0,2\pi)?$

If $0<a<1$, then $f^{-1}[(a, \infty)] = (0, \pi)$?

And if $-1<a<0,$ then $f^{-1}[(a, \infty)] = \emptyset$?

I’m not sure if I’m getting this right here?

Comment: In the quote at the top you do not say what $f(x)$ is. Later it seems it is the sine function. An omission in question?

Comment: Yes. I added that.

Comment: No, you're not getting it right. Consider $a = 2/3$. Then $\sin \frac{\pi}{6} = 1/2 < 2/3$, so $\frac{\pi}{6} \notin f^{-1}[(a, \infty)]$. But according to you, $f^{-1}[(a, \infty)] = (0, \pi)$.

Comment: Not sure I understand this correctly. Would $f^{-1}[(a, \infty)] = (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: @Wondera: Ask yourself: what is $f[(0,\frac \pi 2)]$? Is it $(a,\infty)$ for the choice of $a$ considered?

Comment: @Wondera, for $a=2/3$, your $f^{-1}[(a,\infty)]$ would be $$f^{-1}[(2/3,\infty)]=\{x\in[0,2\pi]\mid 2/3\lt f(x)\lt\infty\}=(k,\pi-k)$$ where $k=\arcsin(2/3)$, for the map $f(x)=\sin x$. Try drawing the graph of $\sin(x)$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and identify the preimages for all open sets $(a,b)$ in $\Bbb R$, it will help you to understand how to construct the induced topology.